# Как вывести массив с помощью api?

Tags: php, api

У меня есть форма, где надо писать счет-фактуру, мне нужно чтобы когда я писал на поле `СЧ-111111/11` мне выводил этот счет из `api`

```
 $url = "getinvoice/";
 $api->post = array(
    'invoice' => 'СЧ-111111/11',
    );
 $vehicle = $api->sendrequest($url);
 echo '<details><summary>getinvoice</summary>';
 echo '<p><pre>';
 print_r($api->post);
 print_r($vehicle);
 echo '</pre></p></details>';
 exit;
```

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: я так понимаю в приведенном коде выполняется нужный запрос на апи, что он возвращает?

Comment: @Skywave у меня есть форма заполнения, когда я туда ввожу например счет 111111-11, то мне на странице должен вывести invoice СЧ-111111-11 из api которую я указал, просто это слово надо вывести, но обязательно с помощью api

Comment: просто вывести слово - `echo "invoice СЧ-111111-11";` Если надо с помощью апи - то вам надо изучить это апи =) все апи разные, неизвестно что они принимают и как отвечают

Comment: Покажи ответ АПИ на отправки твоего счета